# If specific month show content

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which finds a specific month of the year, what I want to do is to show content which includes images, text and a URL if on a specified month.

The code I have to find the month is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const monthToCheck = 8;
const d = new Date();
if(monthToCheck >= d.getMonth() + 1) {
 SHOW CONTENT
}
</script>
```

This is the SHOW CONTENT I want to see

```
<a href="/theurl.php">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="/images/front-page/autumn.jpg" alt="" class="fpimage" style="border:0px;"/>      
      <h4>some text</h4>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is this possible, please?

Comment: using styles it is possible - set the `style="display:none"` for the `<a>` tag, and in javascript set `.style.display=''` if the condition is met

Comment: Any chance of a fiddle or something to show me what you mean please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `style` tag. Refer the below code snippet:

```js
var monthToCheck = 8;
var d = new Date();
if(monthToCheck >= d.getMonth() + 1) {
//SHOW CONTENT
document.getElementById("aid").style.display="";
}
```

```html
<a id="aid" style="display:none" href="/theurl.php">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="/images/front-page/autumn.jpg" alt="" class="fpimage" style="border:0px;"/>      
      <h4>some text</h4>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

1. Add a common class to all your content blocks you want, e.g. `class="months`
2. Add unique ids to each block, e.g. `id=month8` - if you use the month number it will make it easier to identify in the code
3. You can hide all months using `getElementsByClassName`:

```
    var months = document.getElementsByClassName("months");
    for (i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
        months[i].style.display = "none";
```

4. To show the month(s) you want, you can use `getElementById`

```
      document.getElementById("month" + monthToCheck).style.display = "block";
```

**Working Example:**

```js
const monthToCheck = 9;
const d = new Date();

// hide all months
var months = document.getElementsByClassName("months");
for (i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
  months[i].style.display = "none";

if (monthToCheck >= d.getMonth() + 1) {
  document.getElementById("month" + monthToCheck).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="months" id="month8">
  <a href="/theurl.php">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-400-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="fpimage" style="border:0px;" />
      <h4>some text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="months" id="month9">
  <a href="/theurl.php">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-400-300-5.jpg" alt="" class="fpimage" style="border:0px;" />
      <h4>some text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**SHOW CONTENT BASED ON SEASON**

If you want to show content for the season that a month is in, this needs t obe done in a slightly different way, because there isn't a direct 1-to-1 relationship between the date and the season.

First you just need to add the seasons as ids to the classes:

```
<div class="season" id="spring">
  Content here...
</div>
```

and then use this function:

```
var seasons = ["spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"];
function showSeason(monthToCheck) {
    seasonToShow = seasons[Math.floor(monthToCheck/3)];
    document.getElementById(seasonToShow).style.display = "block";
}
// e.g.
today = new Date();
showSeason(today.getMonth());
```

**How this works:**

1. The season names as `id`s match the season names in the array
2. We calculate the position of the season using the month to check (note both month returned by `getMonth` and the season index are zero-based) `Math.floor(monthToCheck/3)` - month 2 will be `2/3` = `0` = spring
3. Use this to get the season from the array, e.g. `seasons[0]` = spring
   4  Use this id to get the correct content using `document.getElementById` and show it

**Working Example**

```js
var seasons = ["spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"];
const d = new Date();

hideAllSeasons(); // if required to hide any existing content
showSeason(d.getMonth());

function showSeason(monthToCheck) {
  // use the month number to get the season
  seasonToShow = seasons[Math.floor(monthToCheck / 3)];
  document.getElementById(seasonToShow).style.display = "block";
}

function hideAllSeasons() {
  var seasonBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("season");
  for (i = 0; i < seasonBlocks.length; i++)
    seasonBlocks[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="season" id="spring">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" />
  <h4>SPRING</h4>
</div>

<div class="season" id="summer">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" />
  <h4>SUMMER</h4>
</div>

<div class="season" id="autumn">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" />
  <h4>AUTUMN</h4>
</div>

<div class="season" id="winter">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" />
  <h4>WINTER</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use your code between a set on months, say between Jan and march show ths block, between april and july show different block?

Comment: @Jase Yes, it can easily be changed to do that. There are a few ways to do it, so the best way depends on exactly what you want to do - I presume we're talking seasons here? It will need an array or some other way to associate the months and seasons... I can add that in if you like?

Comment: ohh, yes please, I really need to show different blocks for every 3 months of the year (autumn, winter, spring, and summer), if poss

Comment: @Jase I have this ready, but it is actually a different question to the one you asked, which was about a specific month. Changing the question is against SO guidelines, so if you want to ask another question and add a comment here to alert me, and I'll post your answer there :)

Comment: @Jase I've updated this question with the changes you asked for so I don't lose them :)

Comment: @Jase Have you added the other question yet so I can move my answer to it? It really doesn't below here and I don't want downvotes for answering a question that wasn't asked!